# ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error when connecting to an oracle database from asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I am getting  ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error when connecting to an oracle database from asp.net application.

Error Frequency: Not consistent and works fine one time and throws error next time

Environment Detail
Oracle Managed Data Access v12.2.1100
Visual Studio 2015
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition

Error Stack Trace
Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x80004005): ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I would appreciate any solution to this issue as it is difficult to figure out myself and tried changing code but no help.

Comment: please try to turn on debug trace both on oracle server and client side for further diagnose

Comment: There is a similar question already posted-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122395/odp-net-managed-driver-throws-ora-12570-network-session-unexpected-packet-read Please check this out.